# port swift in react native deprecated function

Tags: objective-c, react-native

i'm porting swift code on React Native with Objective-C, there is a function that is deprecated what's the correct one
[image]

fixing with void doesn't work if i try to import swift func in react native and then run the app

the code in **RNWebViewManager** and **AwesomeProject...Header** is respectively

**RNWebViewManager**

```
import Foundation


@objc(RNWebVeiewManager)
class RNWebViewManager(): RCTViewManager {
  override func view() -> UIView! {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "hello there"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    return label
  }
}
```

**AwesomeProject...Header**

```
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "React/RCTViewManager.h"
```

Comment: You need to import RNWebViewManager.h

Comment: where this file must be imported

Comment: In RNWebViewManager.m. That’s what the error says : you cannot declare the interface category if you do not specify (aka import) the original interface definition.

Comment: it doesn't have sense RNWebViewManager.h does not exist in my project in fact it gives me the error: 'RNWebViewManager.h' file not found

Comment: Where is RCT_EXTERN_MODULE declared ?

Comment: You must create a file named RNWebViewManager.h  which declared the interface for RNWebViewManager. Then in RNWebViewManager.m import it and declare the implementation of the class. BTW declaring inheritance and protocol conformance in Objective-C is done with : @interface className: parentClassName <protocolName, orherProtocolName..>